# Sending a dynamic Variable to an onclick event for google analytics

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-analytics

I am look for a solution to this

I am trying to track an event in Google analytics using the onclick event but I need to pass a dynamic variable to the url field Please see below code

```
  <asp:hyperlink ID="Hyperlink2" runat="server" Font-Size="8pt" 
  NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("URL") %>' 
  Target="_blank" CssClass="flatorange" 
  style="margin-bottom:10px;" 
  onclick="ga('send', 'event', '<%# Eval("URL") %>');">Apply Now</asp:hyperlink>
  <br />
```

Answer (score 0):

An event has four required parameters and you're only passing three.

Should be (at a minimum):

```
ga('send', 'event', '<%# Eval("URL")%>', 'event action');
```

More info on Events here - [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events).

Comment: I tried that, it looks like the issue is with the dynamic variable if I replace it with an actual label, it works, just cant insert it dynamically                                                       onclick="ga('send', 'event','Testcategory', 'Click', '<%# Eval("URL")%>');"

Comment: Can you share the site at all? Do you see any errors firing onclick? Try removing the single quotes?

Comment: the page doesn't load at all, gives me a parse error, referencing the line when I add the dynamic variable into the ga code. Tried removing the single quotes, same error, There should be a way to bypass hardcoded values